# Showing Turing machines are more computationally powerful than Finite State Machines

Tags: turing-machines, computability

I've been pondering on whether Finite State Machines, particularly [Mealy machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealy_machine), can describe any computable function as Turing machines do. However "Mealy-computability" does not seem to be a term Google likes, and the most I was able to find was an answer in a [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16315/difference-between-a-turing-machine-and-a-finite-state-machine/52630#52630) of this website:

"Turing Machines have has more computational power than FSM. There are tasks which no FSM can do, but which Turing Machines can do."

Yet no proof as to why.

---

**What is an example of a computable function that cannot be expressed by means of Mealy machines?**

Answer (score 1):

A Mealy machine (and more generaly a subsequential transducer) is a FSM that preserves regularity, meaning that if $L$ is a regular language and $M$ is a Mealy machine, then $\varphi_M(L)$ is regular.

A Turing machine can transform a regular language in a non-regular language. For example, it could turn $\{a^n\mid n\geqslant 0\}$ (which is regular) into $\{a^nb^n\mid n\geqslant 0\}$ (which is well-known as a non-regular language).